# Calculating Prime Numbers using Sets, C++

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, set

I am trying to calculate the prime numbers using a set but when I do the calculation my iterator is jumping randomly.

I am trying to implement this method for an value of N=10.

> Choose an integer n. This function will compute all prime numbers up
>   to n. First insert all numbers from 1 to n into a set. Then erase all
>   multiples of 2 (except 2); that is, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, .... Erase all
>   multiples of 3, that is, 6, 9, 12, 15, ... . Go up to sqrt(n) . The
>   remaining numbers are all primes.

When I run my code, it erases 1 and then pos jumps to 4? I am not sure why this happens instead of it going to the value 2 which is the 2nd value in the set?

Also what happens after I erase a value that the iterator is pointing to, what does the iterator point to then and if I advance it where does it advance?

Here is the code:

```
set<int> sieveofEratosthenes(int n){ //n = 10

    set<int> a;
    set<int>::iterator pos = a.begin();

//generate set of values 1-10
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        a.insert(i);
        if(pos != a.end())
            pos++;
    }

    pos = a.begin();

    //remove prime numbers
    while (pos != a.end())
    {
        cout << "\nNew Iteration \n\n";

        for (int i = 1; i < sqrt(n); i++) {
            int val = *pos%i;

            cout << "Pos = " << *pos << "\n";
            cout << "I = " << i << "\n";
            cout << *pos << "/" << i << "=" << val << "\n\n";

            if (val == 0) {
                a.erase(i);
                }
            }
        pos++;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: The Sieve of Eratosthenes does not use any form of divisibility test. You can perform it by hand without knowing any arithmetic at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your implementation is incorrect in that it is trying to combine the sieve algorithm with the straightforward algorithm of trying out divisors, and it does so unsuccessfully. You do not need to test divisibility to implement the sieve - in fact, that's a major contributor to the beauty of the algorithm! You do not even need multiplication.

```
a.erase(1);
pos = a.begin();
while (pos != a.end()) {
    int current = *pos++;
    // "remove" is the number to remove.
    // Start it at twice the current number
    int remove = current + current;
    while (remove <= n) {
        a.erase(remove);
        // Add the current number to get the next item to remove
        remove += current;
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/zhyahV)

Comment: Nice! `while (pos != a.end() && (*pos) * (*pos) < n)` would also meet the "Go up to sqrt(n)" requirement.

Comment: does *pos++ first assign to current and then increment after?

Comment: @user2076774 `*pos++` behaves like a pointer: it produces the current value at the iterator `pos`, and then stores the incremented value into the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

When erasing elements inside a loop you have to be carefull with the indices. For example, when you erase the element at position 0, then the next element is now at position 0. Thus the loop should look something like this:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < sqrt(n); /*no increment*/) {
        /* ... */
        if (val == 0) {
            a.erase(i);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Actually, you also have to take care that the size of the set is shrinking while you erase elements. Thus you better use iterators:

```
    for (auto it = a.begin(); i != a.end(); /*no increment*/) {
        /* ... */
        if (val == 0) {
            a.erase(it);
        } else {
            it++;
        }
    }
```

PS: the above is not exactly what you need for the sieve, but it should be sufficient to demonstrate how to erase elements (I hope so).